# How to change the axis color of javafx chart?

Tags: java, javafx, charts, colors, axis

I am new in javafx. I am using javafx charts (line chart) and want to change the axis color, which is indicated by red circle.

[image]

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

`.axis:left {-fx-border-color: transparent #0f0f0f transparent transparent;}
.axis:bottom{-fx-border-color: #0f0f0f transparent transparent;}`